# Trying a create a object using jsonata from existing object

Tags: javascript, jsonata

Trying to create object out of existing object using jsonata. When the data and expression is put in jsonata excerciser, correct result is generated. However when I run it in Javascript program, errors are generated.

following is javascript code

```
const data = {
    "compCode": "0006",
    "compState": "MH",
    "recvDocNo": "0075",
    "buCode": "AC",
    "branchCode": "001",
    "recvLines": [
        {
            "lineNo": 1,
            "itemId": "00002",
            "qtyAccept": 10,
            "unitRate": 100,
            "basicVal": 1000,
            "taxableAmt": 1000,
        }
    ]
};

let expr = {
    "compCode": compCode,
    "buCode": buCode,
    "lineNo": recvLines.lineNo,
    "itemId": recvLines.itemId
};

jsonata(expr).evaluate(data);
```

I get error - ReferenceError: compCode is not defined

when I change it to data.compCode and all other object properties similarly, I get an error TypeError: path.charAt is not a function.
Could someone tell me how to get it working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `jsonata()` expects a string expression as a parameter, which isn't explicitly stated in the docs, but is shown in the [In Nodejs](http://docs.jsonata.org/using-nodejs) section.

```js
const data = {
    "compCode": "0006",
    "compState": "MH",
    "recvDocNo": "0075",
    "buCode": "AC",
    "branchCode": "001",
    "recvLines": [
        {
            "lineNo": 1,
            "itemId": "00002",
            "qtyAccept": 10,
            "unitRate": 100,
            "basicVal": 1000,
            "taxableAmt": 1000,
        },
         {
            "lineNo": 2,
            "itemId": "00006",
            "qtyAccept": 10,
            "unitRate": 100,
            "basicVal": 1000,
            "taxableAmt": 1000,
        }
    ]
};

let expr = `{
  "compCode": compCode, 
  "buCode": buCode, 
  "lineNo": recvLines.lineNo, 
  "itemId": recvLines.itemId
  }`;

console.log(jsonata(expr).evaluate(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata@1.8.5/jsonata.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am working on creating a transformation template for my ERP using jsonata and got stuck on the very first attempt at using it. s

Comment: Since the problem is solved now, My next issue is how to pass on variables to jsonata expression instead of hard coded properties. I will give it a try and would like to seek your help, if you are willing to such unsolicited help. Thank again.

Comment: Yes, that's no problem. It should be fairly trivial since you're passing a template literal already, but if you'd like to post another question with the details I'll take a look.